# How to access components efficiently when reusing layouts

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a form that has same repeating UI components. So i created a seperate xml file and use it with include tag. Now i want to handle the clicks of the components in the repeated layouts. 
[image: layout]
Using repeating layout with include tag

```
<include android:id="@+id/ml" layout="@layout/safe_risk_layout" />
```

Currently i'm using them as like this

```
ml = findViewById(R.id.ml);
btnmlnote = ml.findViewById(R.id.btnnote);
btnmlphoto = ml.findViewById(R.id.btnphoto);
```

But because of the lot of repeating components there are lot to define like this. So i want to know that is there any way to use this an efficient way. Like, by defining a one class that handle the repeating component click events seperately. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You can create a compound `View`. Basically, create a custom class that extends whichever `ViewGroup` is the root of that `<include>` layout, put everything else into a layout with `<merge>` tags as the root, and inflate that layout into the `ViewGroup` in its constructor. Then you add whatever customizations you like to make it easier to treat it as a single `View`; e.g., custom listener `interface`s, setters/getters, etc. [The dev page section on this is horrendous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound), but there are plenty of decent examples out there.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, i had used a compound view. But how can i use intent inside compound view? As in the layout when user clicked on the photo icon there is a intent passing to open the camera app or gallery. So i need to write a startactivityforresult and onactivity result methods. But that methods cant write inside the compound view. Im calling this compound views from a fragment class. Can you help me with it?

Comment: That's not something that a `View` should be handling. You want the `Activity` or `Fragment` handling that, so use an `interface` to relay that click out to the `Activity`/`Fragment`. You could create your own `interface` – e.g., `OnPhotoClickListener` – and a setter method for it. Alternatively, you could just use the `OnClickListener` interface, and make a method something like `setPhotoIconOnClickListener()`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, its working great thank you for your help. one more thing, it is not related to this question, now i'm capturing a image from camera and use that image in a pdf. When i'm getting the path of that captured image did i want to save it someware temporarily and delete it after generating pdf? i dont want user to show that image in the gallery.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're asking, but yes, if you don't need the image after creating the PDF, then you should delete it.

Comment: Actually i'm asking that is there anyway to capture a image from camera and write it to pdf without saving that captured image to the gallery? Currently i'm doing it by saving the captured image in pictures folder and do the pdf writing. Is there anyway to do it without saving to the storage? Like saving it temporarily in the memory and done the writing.

Comment: If you're talking about a full resolution image from an external camera app, then you have to save it to a file somewhere. However, if you save it to your app's internal storage, it won't show up in the gallery.

Comment: no i don t want a full resolution image, i'm just scaled the bitmap to smaller resolution and im using the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent. so it it the default camera app. currently i'm saving the captured image and use it path to write to the pdf. because of saving it in pictures it is showing in the gallery. i dont want user to see images that are captured by the app. i want to temporarily save that captured image in someware until write to the pdf.

Comment: If you put an `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the camera `Intent`, then the camera app is going to save a sizable image to a file, because it's too big to pass back on the result `Intent`. It doesn't really matter what resolution you end up using; it has to save it to a file. If that's how you want to do it, then you can create the target file in your internal storage instead. However, if you don't pass an `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, then the camera app should pass back a thumbnail image on the data `Intent` in `onActivityResult()`. If that's sufficient, then it shouldn't be saved anywhere, but that might vary by app.

Comment: i had used EXTRA_OUTPUT and save the image in pictures, But if i dont pass that intent EXTRA_OUTPUT property how can i get the image path that is returned by camera intent? As you say if camera intent used without EXTRA_OUTPUT, it will passing back a thumbnail image. But how can i get that passed thumbnail image location to write it to pdf. it can be captured to a Bitmap using returned uri.

Comment: That thumbnail will be passed back directly as an extra on the data `Intent` in `onActivityResult()`. IIRC, its key is ``"data"``, so you can get it with something like `Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`.

Comment: ok i got it, then how can i get the absolute path of that bitmap? i need the exact path before it correctly write to the pdf file

Comment: There is no path. It's an in-memory `Bitmap` object.

Comment: ok then i think that method is not suitable for write to pdf. because i cant directly write bitmap image to the pdf. i need the file location and convert it to a image file before using it in pdf